# Paying cash to hotel in advance for a few days

Tags: germany, hotels

I'm planning to stay in a hotel in Germany for a night, then travel elsewhere for a few days, before coming back to the same hotel for several nights. I'm worried about the cash that I'll be carrying while traveling, in case it is stolen.

Is it likely to be okay if I ask the hotel when I get there that I want to pay for all the nights for which I'll be staying there?

Comment: Have you asked the hotel?

Comment: In order to hit credit card offers, I've been known to try to pay hotels in advance in cases when they haven't needed pre-payment. It can be done, but it is often a surprisingly large amount of work for both yourself and their finance team!

Comment: Given you are returning to the same hotel could you ask to put some cash (and potentially other items) in their safe for them to hold until you return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no answer on this question as this highly depends on the hotel you want to stay: So check with the hotel. But this being said: It's not very common to pay cash in advance so expect some surprised questions. 
Maybe paying with debit or credit card would be an better idea, as you don't have to carry cash with you but don't need to pay in advance.